# Eclipse plugin migration Kepler to Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I'm in a migration of a eclipse plugin from Kepler version to Luna.
I have have this error :

```
Discouraged access: The type 'ProxyManager' is not API (restriction on required library '/srv/data204139/dchesnea/LUNA/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.core.net_1.2.200.v20140124-2013.jar')
```

Have you an idea ?

Comment: Yes for use my plugin in Luna version of eclipse.

Comment: Please be more precise: do you just want to upgrade eclipse to a newer version; while keeping all installed plugins? Or are you talking about problems with a plugin that **you** developed on your own? And just a side note: I found that moving to a new eclipse major version is often a good time to clean up things. Meaning: don't upgrade an existing work space; just create a new one, import your projects there; and install the plugins (again) that you are normally using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager` is in an **internal** package and is therefore not part of the official Eclipse API - you should not be using it ([Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)).

Some of the functions of the proxy manager are available through the `org.eclipse.core.net.proxy.IProxyService` OSGi service which is part of the official API.